# Error encountered when importing modules in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When I install modules with command `npm install <module_name> -g`, I'm able to import module in Node.js command line via `require()`，

but when I execute `node <path/name.js>` to run my code，I encountered `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error

Comment: And the module not found is the module you installed via `npm install <module_name> -g`?

Comment: @WakaChewbacca Yes.

Comment: Normal you dont just download a module an "execute" it. You write your own code and `require` the module there and use the exposed functions/methods. What package are we talking about? Take a moment an take the SO tour and how to ask questions!

Comment: @Marc you didn't understand my question. <path/name.js> stand for my script that try to require module, by the way the module is Needle

Answer (score -1):

When you run your script nodejs search inside your project to find the desired module, if it is not found it will not search for the global.

So, you need to install the module in your project dir, by running the command

```
npm install <module>
```

This will create the node_modules folder, and your script will found the module.

You can understanding better about module are handled reading the official node documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module

Comment: "if it is not found it will not search for the global" then whats the point of the global folder?! Thats just false. If the package was not found node looks upwards all directorys for "node_modules" if you root/mount point of the drive is reached, it search in the global directory. Your answer is false. BTW: Your link has nothing to do how the module lookup works.

Comment: Hi Marc. By default node doesn't look to the global node_modules folder, you can "force" it to search in that folder by setting the NODE_PATH env var, but it is not recommended: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders "It is strongly encouraged to place dependencies in the local node_modules folder. These will be loaded faster, and more reliably."

Comment: Then whats the purpose of install packages with `-g` flag? To use it global. And to achive that node has to lookup the global folder. From your link, "Additionally, Node.js will search in the following list of GLOBAL_FOLDERS" You just confirmed what im saying. "NODE_PATH" is to customize/add additional folder for the global path searching. https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together

Comment: The purpose to install modules globally is for example to use a cli application, but not to use them within our projects. https://soshace.com/5-lessons-node-js-global-modules/

Comment: @Winslow And what was the problem?! Answer your Question if you found a solution!

Comment: @Marc This answer solved the problem... as this answer mentioned, run npm install in the directory of your project

Comment: @Winslow Then mark it as answer to help other

Comment: @Marc oh okay, sorry I'm not really familiar with StackOverflow